# Injectivity of Fourier series in a horizontal strip

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to prove (or give a counter-example, which I couldn't find) the following statement:

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be such that $g(x)=g(x+2 \pi)$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n} c_{n}e^{inx}$, then for points $x, y$ in the horizontal strip $|x-y|<2 \pi$, $g$ is injective.

My reasoning went like this:

Let $g(x)=g(y)$, for $x$, $y$ such that $|x-y|<2 \pi$.

Since $g$ can be writen in complex Fourier series, by Cantor's theorem, it follows that $c_ne^{inx}=c_ne^{iny}$, for at least one $n$. But this implies, since $|x-y|<2 \pi$, that $x=y$. Proving the proposition.

That was what I thought, if someone can help with a counter-example or some comments on the proof, I thank you a lot.

Edited: I'll try to be clearer.

I'm trying to prove (or give a counter-example) to the following statement:

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be such that $g(x)=g(x+2 \pi)$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n} c_{n}e^{inx}$, then there exist points $x, y$ with $|x-y|<2 \pi$ in such a way that $g(x)=g(y)$ implies $x=y$, so for the set of these points $g$ is injective.

What I thought was to let $g(x)=g(y)$, for $x$, $y$ such that $|x-y|<2 \pi$.

Then, by the uniqueness of Fourier series, it follows that $c_ne^{inx}=c_ne^{iny}$, for at least one $n$, (and here is my doubt, because I don't know what is meant by a Fourier series to be the same, I just imagine that if it has the same Fourier coefficients, then at least one term in the expansion must be different for different points, since is the same function.). But this implies, since $|x-y|<2 \frac{\pi}{|n|}<2 \pi$, that $x=y$. Proving the proposition.

My main doubt is this: if a function has a Fourier expansion, is it true that for two different points $x, y$ in its domain, at least one term in the expansion of $x$ will differ from that of $y$? (Excluding the constant function).

Sorry if the first question was confusing. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Cantor's theorem? Everything looks wrong in your question.

Comment: @reuns I edited, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: No, it is not. In what sense is $\cos(x)$ "injective".

Comment: As @reuns said, there's a lot that's wrong with this question. I recommend going over it again.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, it looks like you might be trying to prove that for some interval $J$ with length less than $2 \pi$ we have that $g$ is injective on $J$. That's not what you wrote though and I'm just guessing.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. To find a restriction to the domain of $g$, where g is always injective. For instance $0<x<\pi$ for cos$(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you conceivably want to claim that, given a non-constant periodic function $g$, on a sufficiently small interval $g$ is injective? Please advise. That's certainly not true, anyway, because we can have _piecewise_ constant smooth functions (that are non-constant). (The smoothness assures that their Fourier series converges uniformly and absolutely pointwise to the function's pointwise values.)

Comment: @paul garret. Yes it would be basically that. So the counter-example would be some function that is piecewise constant and smooth, therefore certainly not injective. Well, I think I understood, just can't visualize it. (As you can ser I'm new to Fourier series). But thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is "not natural" to have a "nice" function constant for a while, and then _smoothly_ does something else. Not likely to happen "by accident". But _can_ happen. Perhaps start up on this idea by ignoring Fourier series for a bit, and just thinking about how to make L. Schwartz's infamous "test functions" on $\mathbb R$, namely, smooth (and not just identically $0$!) functions of compact support. Start with the classic riff that $f$ on $\mathbb R$ defined to be $0$ for $x<0$, $0$ at $x=0$, and $e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ is indeed infinitely differentiable at $0$, and all derivatives are $0$. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) $f(x)=\sum a^n\cos(b^n\pi x), 0<a<1, b=2k+1, ab>1+3\pi/2$

Then $f$ (given as a Fourier series) is continuous and nowhere differentiable which means there is no interval $(c,d)$ where it is injective as it would be monotonic there (by continuity) and hence differentiable ae there by Lebesgue's theorem